# How to filter state with React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I make an api req at the mounting of my component:

```
  await fetch('/api/visited')
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((data) => setCountries(data.payload))
```

then I set the state to be the countries

but when I try filtering on this it's overriding my state and im losing all the data. how can I retain the data and make a copy of it?

pre hooks I think I used `prevState`

```
<input onChange={(e) => filterCountries(e)} />

const filterCountries = (e) => {
    setCountries(countries.filter((country) => country.name.includes(e.target.value)))
}
```

this is what I've tried but it's overriding state, how can I fix this?

I've seen other answers on this saying "use the original state" but that comes from an api so I cant do that unless I store that separately but then I'll have 2 sources of truth and I dont want that

Comment: Why not define two states? One for original and one for filter.

Comment: @BeHappy seems like a bad way of doing it

Comment: means I have to set state twice at the mounting of my component

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overriding the payload you got from you API call.
every time you use `setCountries` you are setting a **new** value to the countries variable.
what you should do is derive the filtered countries from the `countries` variable and use that for displaying the result.

try introducing a new state for the filter

```js
const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
```

Then you input will be

```js
<input onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)} />
```

Now in your component body add a new variable for the filtered countries
const filteredCountries = countries ? countries.filter((country) => country.name.includes(filter))) : []

and use `filteredCountries` in your render